# '..\node_modules\pngquant-bin\vendor\pngquant.exe' is missing

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin-feed

E:\Gatsby\ecom-gatsby>gatsby develop
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.349s
success load plugins - 19.895s
success onPreInit - 0.036s
success initialize cache - 0.454s
⠋ copy gatsby files

ERROR

UNHANDLED REJECTION Processing E:/Gatsby/ecom-gatsby/src/images/gatsby-astronaut.png failed

Original error:
'E:\Gatsby\ecom-gatsby\node_modules\pngquant-bin\vendor\pngquant.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

WorkerError: Processing E:/Gatsby/ecom-gatsby/src/images/gatsby-astronaut.png failed
  Original error:
  'E:\Gatsby\ecom-gatsby\node_modules\pngquant-bin\vendor\pngquant.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.

- jobs-manager.js:314 exports.enqueueJob
  [ecom-gatsby]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/jobs-manager.js:314:23
- task_queues.js:94 processTicksAndRejections
  internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5

not finished copy gatsby files - 0.157s

Comment: ok, so you've send us the console output. What is exactly your issue?

Answer (score 4):

Solving this issue by installing two npm packages...

Fixed by using older imagemin-pngquan and pngquant-bin library versions

**npm install imagemin-pngquant@5.0.1 --save
npm install pngquant-bin@3.1.1 --save```**

Make sure that run command with root/Administrator permission.